# Get initialized object among many undefined ones in one statment

Tags: javascript

I have three objects (ob1, ob2, ob3) and among three only one is defined and I don't know which one. I want to store that defined objects' value in a variable in  one statement i.e. without using IFs and ELSEs.
Something like below.

```
var object = ob1 || ob2 ||ob3
```

Comment: What you've got (assuming the last `ob2` is really `ob3`) will work fine.

Comment: @Pointy, sorry corrected it

Comment: please clarifiy between your meaning of `null`: `undefined` and/or other falsey values.

Comment: What does ob1/2/3 look like when it has a value and when it does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with your current approach?  That is correct logic:

```
var obj1 = null;
var obj2 = 'hello';
var obj3 = null;

var obj4 = obj1 || obj2 || obj3;

console.log(obj4);
// hello
```

**After your edit**:  I don't believe there is any quick and easy way to get the first `undefined` value like the null coalescing check, but here's a shot at a "one-liner":

```
//var obj1 = undefined;
var obj2 = 'hello';
//var obj3 = undefined;

var obj4 = 
  (typeof obj1 === "undefined" ? null: obj1) ||
  (typeof obj2 === "undefined" ? null: obj2) ||
  (typeof obj3 === "undefined" ? null: obj3);

console.log(obj4);
// hello
```

Uses the same logic, virtually just converting `undefined` into `null` to still leverage the one-liner coalesce.

Comment: what about false and empty string?

Comment: @DanielA.White ... the OP states he's looking for the first non null.  No mention of false or empty string.  No need to over-engineer the answer for "just in case".

Comment: If the OP knows that the variables refer either to objects or to nothing, then there may be no point worrying about other falsy values.

Comment: `"" !== null`, `false !== null` and `undefined !== null`

Comment: @DanielA.White Where do you see the requirement to check for false?  That appears to have been fabricated by you..?

Comment: @DanielA.White so?  this will still find the first of those variables that contains a reference to an object (as opposed to something like `null` or `undefined`, or of course `false`, `0`, `""`, or `NaN`).

Comment: `false || null` will return `null`! the OP is explicitly asking for non-null values.

Comment: @DanielA.White From the details the OP provided, the OP says it is an object or null.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said UNDEFINED.